# Objective C dateformatter how do i format this

Tags: nsdateformatter

I get the following date from an API

```
"created_at":"Wed Jun 19 20:36:48 +0000 2013"
```

I don't know how to handle the "Wed" and "Jun", can't find any good documentation for this.

```
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"? ? dd HH:mm:ss '+00:00' YYYY"];
```

Comment: Start by studying the spec: http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-25.html#Date_Format_Patterns

Comment: I have done that and tried the following code : [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"ddd mmm dd HH:mm:ss '+00:00' yyyy"]; but it's not working, am i wrong?

Comment: Look at the distinction between "m" and "M".

Comment: You have the wrong codes for the day of the week and the month name.

Comment: @rmaddy What is the correct code? I google this and find different answears .. now im trying [dateFormatter1 setDateFormat:@"ccc LLL dd HH:mm:ss '+00:00' yyyy"]; but it doesnt work either

Comment: Use the format codes in the link given by "Hot Licks" in the first comment. `EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss Z yyyy`.